# Finding first paired string in a string

Tags: c#, string, search

Let's say you have this string:

> "3434989348584934944989353534989".

How do you find the first paired string? In this case I want the output to be 4989.

I want my method to be:

```
static string FindFirst(int length, string stringpair)
{
// code here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: how do you define first paired?

Comment: hint. ```indexof``` 1 possible way

Comment: FindFirst(4, 3434989348584934944989353534989); According to the method argument 4 is the length. The desired output should be 4989.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Maybe you want something [like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64952/find-repeated-substrings-of-length-3-in-a-string) but a little modified to return the _duplicated substring_?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so far, the PO's effort is a commented line of code, you can do better than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement following method:

```
        static string FindFirst(int length, string stringpair)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < stringpair.Length; i++)
            {
                string subStr = stringpair.Substring(i, length);

                if (set.Contains(subStr)) // if contains, then there is already 1 key with same value
                    return subStr;

                set.Add(subStr);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/klIjR4)